# Validation in nested UpdatePanel(s)

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, validation

I have an ASP.Net page which has several UpdatePanels. Each UpdatePanel loads an UserControl, and per UserControl, sub UserControl(s) may exists. In order to achieve partial-refresh, each sub UserControl will be carried through UpdatePanel. Those UserControls have input controls, and corresponding validator server controls.

The problem is, validators in a sub-UserControl will also trigger the validation in its parent UserControl; however, I'd like separate validation into scopes based on UpdatePanel.
Please kindly help.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and .Net 3.5.

Thank you.
William

-- EDITED ---
E.g.

[image]

I've an UserControl called "AddableDropDown" which is a drop down list that provides the ability of adding new list item on the fly. It consists of a drop down list for illustrating the currently available items; a asp:textbox for entering the title for the new item, a asp:button for submitting the new item, and a "RequiredFieldValidator" target on the asp:textbox.

The "AddableDropDown" will be used in different UserControl-based "web form" which has other kinds of inputs and Validators.

The goal I'm trying to reach is separating the Validation of the AddableDropDown from each of its instances, as well as each parent control of it.

Comment: Have you tried out it by having a validation group for the controls

Comment: I asked for the source you have written

Comment: Hi Drobabu, I need some time for getting the source from mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried out it by having a [validationgroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) for the controls in each and every panel

Comment: yes, by trying ValidationGroup, I'm now facing two problems: 1) all instances of a sub-usercontrol will have the same ValidationGroup which causes validation on other non-focused instances. 2) The post-back action of the focused sub-usercontrol will never be fired.

Comment: Can you post the source what you have written

Comment: In order to differentiate the validation scope, the ValidationGroup in re-usable UserControl should able to uniquely identified:
So, within the AddableDropDown.ascx, I generate the ValidationGroup dynamically:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 //... other code...
 in_newtag.ValidationGroup = in_newtag.ValidationGroup + this.ID;
 btn_newtag.ValidationGroup = btn_newtag.ValidationGroup + this.ID;
 //... other code...
}